# LWC - Check checkbox won't work

Tags: lightning-web-components, checkbox

Simple question. This won't work - It won't check my checkbox. Any solutions?

html.

```
<template>
   <lightning-input type="checkbox" data-id="none" label="None of the above" value="None of the above"></lightning-input>
</template>
```

js.

```
  connectedCallback() {
      let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="none"]');
      for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = true;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `connectedCallback()`, the child elements haven't been rendered yet. You need to wait a tick, either by `renderedCallback` or by `Promise.resolve`:

```
// option 1
async connectedCallback() {
  await Promise.resolve();
  [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-element')]
    .forEach((input) => { input.checked = true })
}

// Option 2
_selectedAll
renderedCallback() {
  if(this._selectedAll) {
    return;
  }
  this._selectedAll = true;
  [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-element')]
    .forEach((input) => { input.checked = true })
}
```

You only need one of these two solutions.

Comment: Ah @sfdcfox you are always right! Yeah I totally forgot that connectedCallback() never waits it to be rendered. Thanks! this is really good example.

Comment: @sfdcfox how promise.resolve is interlinked with page rendering?  So refreshing page is a promise that when it resolves, it runs the next lines of code in connectedcallback?

Comment: @PratapM `await Promise.resolve()` returns control to the LWR rendering engine, and after all synchronous code (including `render()` and `renderedCallback()`) have finished, the next line of code will immediately execute. You can use this method any time you want to wait for a render cycle, not just the first. E.g. `this.data = await someApexCall(); await Promise.resolve(); this.template.querySelector('something')`

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for more insights.